# Haskell SDL2 Game - Memory Leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, sdl-2

I want to make a small game in haskell with SDL2 and FRP Yampa.
When I start the game the heap will constantly increase until the game freezes.

I made some profile analysis with ghc, but I can't get any hints where the leak happens.

The source is on github: https://github.com/flomerz/SchaffschNie

I am on Ubuntu 14.10 with GHC 7.10.

```
Running SchaffschNie-Prof...
 106,883,930,776 bytes allocated in the heap
     380,257,040 bytes copied during GC
         301,240 bytes maximum residency (968 sample(s))
          31,584 bytes maximum slop
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     206180 colls,     0 par    1.152s   1.075s     0.0000s    0.0022s
  Gen  1       968 colls,     0 par    0.508s   0.736s     0.0008s    0.1118s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time   84.876s  (108.001s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.476s  (  1.440s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.184s  (  0.371s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  Total   time   86.536s  (109.445s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,259,295,098 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.1% of total user, 77.6% of total elapsed
```

Here are some graphs:
[System Monitor & GHC Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DBvp.png)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you don't deallocate surface, textures you create. For instance in Output/Renderer.hs you might try after the SDL.copy to SDL.freeSurface and SDL.destroyTexture

Comment: Thanks :D This was really the problem. You are my hero :)

Comment: glad to help! Another improvement you can try: move the loading of textures at startup and store them in a datatype. So you only have to use SDL.copy and deallocate them when the game finish. Because right now you are recreating/destroying them all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm already working on it. I'm open to all improvements :)